# How can I tell if jobs are Co-Op or not?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Simple question, is there a way to tell if a job is going to be competitive or cooperative before jumping into it? Went through a nice set of jobs last night and it was hard to figure out which game play style they were before we were just running them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, I went out hunting for data and I found that in general the following rules apply.

If the mission is given to you from an NPC chances are that all people partaking in it will be on the same team and attempting to accomplish the missions. Not all of these types of missions accept more than one person but a good amount of them can take 2+ people in them. These missions will be given to you via your phone from a text message.

If the mission is started from roaming the city and walking into a trigger, these are generally head to head missions.

While these guides do not cover 100% of the missions on either side of the fence it is a general guide of what missions to look to do whether you want to do Co-Op with your invited friends or competitive against your invited friends.

Source: http://gta.wikia.com/Missions_in_GTA_Online

Answer (score 2):

I believe that most missions given to you by a character can be completed as cooperative missions while most missions you encounter while moving around the open world, with the exception of gang shootouts, are generally competitive.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell every mission can be done with more than 1 person. If you try and do a harder mission by yourself you will sometimes be prompted with "This is a harder mission and may require more than 1 person to complete".

From video content I would say that most if not every mission can be co-oped.

While straying away from actual VS missions, you can still do "Campaign Missions" with more than one person. However some missions have a maximum of 2 people.

Comment: I think I need to make my question a bit more clear.. Races you are competing against each other.. Last Team Standing you compete against each other.. But then there is 'Rescue Anna' which I do not recall the actual mission name or anything, but it was 3-4 of us all on the same team vs AI.. That is the distinction I am trying to find out. My friends and I like playing With each other not against each other.

Comment: @James Then let me re-word the answer.